# Xpath: Select elements based on descendants that do not have a certain attribute

Tags: xpath

I am scraping through real estate listings from a certain site that contains multiple pages.

Here, I have summarized a structure nested deep in the DOM. I want to select all list items, based on the descendants that **do not** have a certain attribute name like `<div id="nav-ad-container">`

```
<ul class="photo-cards photo-cards_wow photo-cards_short photo-cards_extra-attribution">
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>
        <div id="nav-ad-container" class="zsg-aspect-ratio"></div>
      </li>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
</ul>
```

However, given that the attribute and the attribute's name change in the DOM for each page.

**For example**:

```
@id = 'nav-ad-container' or @class = 'nav-ad-empty'
```

In general, I want to retrieve the list items that do not contain the name pattern `'nav-ad`'.

Things that I've tried with no success (still selects every list item)

```
xpath + //li[not(contains(@class, 'nav-ad'))]
xpath + //li[not((contains(@class,'nav-ad')) or contains(@id,'nav-ad'))]
```

Can anyone guide me toward a solution? I feel like I'm pretty close but missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
//li[not(descendant-or-self::node()/@class[contains(.,'nav-ad')])]
```

Answer (score 1):

filter by classname of list items or descendants:

//li[not(contains(descendant-or-self::node()/@class,'nav-ad'))]

(not tested)

Comment: In XPath 2.0 this will fail (in the general case, though not for this particular example) because the argument of contains() is a sequence containing multiple nodes. In XPath 1.0 it will give the wrong answer, because contains() ignores all but the first of those nodes.

Comment: In my case this answer also worked. However, Michael's response gave some extra information that I was not aware of.